# API authentication in laravel

Tags: android, laravel, api, server

I have a server developed in laravel. I have an android application that can send POST and GET request to my server. I found that i can send POST and GET request from any other systems if have the link to my api. I want to authenticate my API and only allow my android application to POST and GET from my API. Please note that i dont have user login in my android part. I simply want to authenticate my android app to access those APIs.

Comment: You can use `Basic Authenticate` on header. But I recommend you using user login for get more secure. I'm using `JWT`. And it's working well until now.

Comment: use token in laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only your mobile application to make API calls, you can't. Your API doesn't know who is sending the information, he can only check if the information is correct and proceed with your endpoint. Like others have said use JWT/Authentication to limit who can use your API by creating an account or requesting a token, but there's nothing to prevent the user from taking his token and use it on his browser or tool of his choice like Postman.